# como especificar valores para ordenar sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Boa tarde!

Galera, tenho a seguinte consulta abaixo, porém, eu quero ordenar especificando alguns registros . Em anexo por exemplo, é a consulta gerado e eu quero que a coluna Valor venha assim: 
Diamante
Ouro
Bronze
Prata

Como especificar para que venha a vir dessa forma?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque a estrutura das suas tabelas e o código que está utilizando, evite colocar o print da sua tela.

Comment: imagino que a "Descrição" deva estar em outra tabela fazendo join no seu select, se este for o caso, colocaria uma propriedade para ordenação nessa outra tabela para evitar o hard-code na query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma coluna de ordem com `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE t.campo
         WHEN 'DIAMANTE' THEN 0
         WHEN 'OURO' THEN 1
         WHEN 'PRATA' THEN 2
         WHEN 'BRONZE' THEN 3
       END AS ordem
  FROM tabela t
 ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que utilizando o order by com um `CASE` resolva seu problema:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE ColunaValor WHEN 'DIAMANTE' THEN 0 
                    WHEN 'OURO' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'PRATA' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'BRONZE' THEN 3
   END
```